# How Can I Have IE Not Cut Off Popup Menu?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11, overflow

I have a parent container with a table inside of it. Each row of the table has a popup menu that can be opened by clicking it. At the bottom of the container, when it is clicked, it shows properly in Chrome/Firefox but IE 11 cuts the menu off at the bottom of the container. I'm sure the fix for this is easy but I'm not sure what it is or how to look it up. I've tried setting the width and height of the parent container with no luck.

Chrome Example:

[image]

IE Example:

[image]

Here is the CSS for the parent container:

```
.payment-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  min-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

Here is the CSS for the menu:

```
  .action-submenu {
    margin-top: 8px;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    border-radius: 3px;
    min-width: 150px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 4000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px -2px rgba(46,46,46,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px -2px rgba(46,46,46,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px -2px rgba(46,46,46,0.5);
  }
```

Any help that could be provided would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE required overflow-x: visible and Chrome/Firefox did not. After working with it for a bit, this was found to be the issue.